# Move to file name starting with the letter which was pressed on the keyboard button

Tags: keyboard, nautilus, files, button

Is there a way to set up the explorer in a way that it moves the selection to the files starting with the letter which was pressed on the keyboard button? 
Just like Mac and Windows handle it for example.